# Label with a formal part and a computed part

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

If would like to print 
$\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2$= (b/a)^2 inside a plot or a graphics where a and b have been seted to certain values so the first part is analytic and the second part (after the =) is computed

Comment: something like `Graphics[Text[Row[{HoldForm[(a/b)^2], "=", (a/b)^2}]]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) to prevent the "formal part" of the label from being evaluated:

```
a = 2; b = 3;
Graphics[{Circle[], 
  Text[Style[ToString[HoldForm[(a/b)^2], TraditionalForm] <> " = " <> 
     ToString[(a/b)^2, TraditionalForm], 24], {1/3, 0}]}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[ToString[HoldForm[(a/b)^2], TraditionalForm] <> " = " <> 
    ToString[(a/b)^2, TraditionalForm], 24]]
```

[image]

You can replace `HoldForm` with [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) to get the same result.